Why does only newly added data appear and not all data?
It looks like this:
I want it to look like this:
Code:
FirebaseUser firebaseKullanici = yetki.getCurrentUser();
String kullaniciId = firebaseKullanici.getUid();
yol = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Kullanıcılar").child("KullaniciId");
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("id", kullaniciId);
hashMap.put("kullaniciAdi", kullaniciAdi.toLowerCase());
hashMap.put("adsoyad", adsoyad);
hashMap.put("bio", "");
hashMap.put("resimurl", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/uygulama-4683b.appspot.com/o/placeholder-user-scaled.jpg?alt=media&token=29e7ea5c-3d37-4d06-a119-badbf3fe944b");              

How can I fix this?

You're getting that schema inside the database because of the "Kullanıcılar" hard-coded value that is passed to the .child("Kullanıcılar") function and because of the call of .child("KullaniciId"). If you want your database to look like this, then please change this line:
yol = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Kullanıcılar").child("KullaniciId");

To:
yol = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(KullaniciId);

See, I have removed the call to .child("Kullanıcılar") and removed the quotes inside .child(KullaniciId)?
Edit:
If you want to group all users within a "users" node for example, then you have to add a call to .child("users") like below:
yol = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                    .child("users"); //
                                    .child(KullaniciId);


How can I group these ids?

To achieve that, please check my updated answer.
